# Add DB User in MySql Workbench or create users table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm doing an application to retrieve data from the database with multiple users. 
I need to add users to the application.

Should I create users using queries such as (create user . . .) or it is better just to create table users and perform all operations there?

Comment: can you give more detail? I didn't understand what you mean by 'Should I create users using queries such as (create user . . .) or it is better just to create table users and perform all operations there?'

Comment: CREATE USER [IF NOT EXISTS]
    user [auth_option] . . . 

Here is the code(sql query) for creating user in MySql.

Should I use the code above in order to create users for my java application 

or just create table `users` in database and use query INSERT INTO `users`  . . . ?

Comment: CREATE USER is used for connectivity from mysql to your application.If your application have multiple users you need to keep all the records in users table and allow authentication by checking this user defined table

Answer (score 0):

If you mean users as web application users, then you should create a table named like `users` and insert user details into it. Creating database users for web application users is meaningless.